# html - initial scale of PDF object

Tags: pdf, html-object

How can I scale an inline PDF when it loads, rather than forcing the user to click one of the two scaling options at the bottom of the PDF?

The width of the parent div the object is in is 680px wide, so when the PDF loads it has horizontal scrolling that I would like to do away with.

```
<div class="content">
    <object data="pdf_link.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="680" height="870">
        <p> It looks like you can't view this PDF, but you can download it <a href="pdf_link.pdf">here</a>.
    </object>
</div>
```

Note: width="100%" doesn't do the trick